# Using javascript to place a transparent image on top of another and another

Tags: javascript, css

I want to be able to assemble a sandwich by selecting what you want on it. Using radio buttons, I want to see the sandwich assemble as you click what you want on it. I've made each individual part of the sandwich, and I want to be able to stack each image on top of another, so I don't have to make 100 unique images and functions. Similar to apps I've used, like Pizza Hut's or Dominoes', to order a pizza, and the image of the pizza changes as you select what you want on it.

Is this possible how I'm explaining it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please update in fiddle

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: well it says my code is too long by 1006 characters. how do i get passed this?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBRLzb

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this.  One way would be to stack background images on top of each other.  You can do this by using the following CSS:

```
.image-container{
    background:
        url(meat.png) no-repeat,
        url(lettuce.png) no-repeat,
        url(bun.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a canvas to render it smoothly

```js
function draw(){
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("1");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
    var img=document.getElementById("2");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);

};
$('#btn').click(function(){draw();});
```

```html
<button id="btn" >Draw </button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="1" width="220" height="277" src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/System/Fruity%20Apples/Seablue%20512.png"  style="display:none;" />
    <img src="https://www.wildcardcorp.com/images/company-logos/mac-icon.png" id="2" style="display:none;" />

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: That seems like severe overkill...

Comment: maybe a bit but it depends what its for, I like it because visible result itself is rendered as and can be saved as an image